# MariaDB - lost db connection

Tags: google-compute-engine, mariadb

I'm new to Google Compute but not CentOS.  I created an instance from Google's stock CentOS 7.2 build and am having trouble with MariaDB, it shuts down once or twice a day and can't start itself back up.  Has anyone else run into this problem?

My db log:

```
161203 19:13:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 512.0M
InnoDB: mmap(551026688 bytes) failed; errno 12
161203 19:13:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
161203 19:13:44 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
161203 19:13:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
161203 19:13:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
161203 19:13:44 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
161203 19:13:44 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)
161203 19:13:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
161203 19:13:44 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
161203 19:13:44 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Things I've tried:

- converted all tables to the InnoDB engine
- added a **MaxClients 128** line to my httpd.conf
- added **innodb-buffer-pool-size=512MB** to the [mysqld] section of my my.cnf file
- added RAM (since dropped the extra RAM because it didn't seem to help)

This is my first post here, so please go easy on me.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: You don't have enough memory for 512M buffer pool, decrease the value. If you started with the default (128M) and even then had the problem, try to set it lower. How much memory do you have total?

Comment: And you will probably need to decrease other settings.  It sound slike you have a _tiny_ VM.

Comment: I updated the buffer pool size to 128MB and will let you know how that goes.
* This is what Google says I have: 1 vCPU, 1.7 GB.
* Is 128 the default buffer pool size?

Comment: Woah - the load shot up and I lost the DB again without any real messages in the DB log this time.  The load on the server shot up and there are 5 apache threads at the top of top.